# How to optimize space between rows and columns using Materializecss

Tags: css, node.js, materialize

I would like to remove the space between the cards. This happens when the cards have different heights. So, I think the framework try to put the row above the highest card.

[image]

My code is like this one:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col s12 m3">
      <div class="card">Profile</div>
   </div>

   <% for(var i = 0 ; i < projects.length; i++){ %
    <div class="col s12 m3">
       <div class="card">
          Projects
       </div>
    </div> 
   <% } %>      
</div>
```

I am using Materializecss to do the website design. 
http://materializecss.com/

The code is here on Github: 
https://github.com/andreluizreis/git-user-assignment

Answer (score 1):

**option #1**

There is this solution that implements what you need: https://github.com/leozdgao/responsive_waterfall, there is a live demo here: http://www.cssscript.com/demo/pinterest-like-responsive-fluid-grid-layout-with-pure-javascript/

**option #2**

The way pinterest implement the cards is a nice way as well, the set all "cards" with position:absolute and inside the loop they calculate the correct position of the card. based on the previous cards. doing that you could arrange all the cards, no matter the height, just setting style="top:y, left:x" at each div.

**option #3**

This article discuss the use of floats vs css3 columns, that should help: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

Comment: I did in a different way. I created 3 columns and I used a for jumping  3 on 3.  Look here the result: https://git-user-assignment.herokuapp.com/

Comment: hi Andre, I'm excited to go to A&W with u tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style to your css:

```css
.card
{
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how a simple `padding` answers the question.